# SPARQL Query returning nothing from fr.dbpedia.org

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using the following SPARQL query to retrieve the IATA code for [Laker Airways](http://dbpedia.org/page/Laker_Airways).

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

select ?airline ?iata where {
   ?airline a dbo:Airline.
   ?airline rdfs:label "Laker Airways"@en.
   OPTIONAL {?airline dbo:iataAirlineCode ?iata.}
}
```

This works against http://dbpedia.org/sparql/ but not against http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql/.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because getting nothing out could be due to no data or a mistake, my usual way to debug is to build the query up line by line. so if you comment out the last two lines before the } and add a LIMIT 10 after the } what do you get? then if it looks OK uncomment the next line, and so on. Oops, you might also have to modify the select line because the iata variable isn't being filled. You know what I mean, I hope.

Comment: Your sparql works for me, pasted it into the endpoint, returns GK  http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E+%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect+%3Fairline+%3Fiata+where+%7B%0D%0A+++%3Fairline+a+dbo%3AAirline.%0D%0A+++%3Fairline+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Laker+Airways%22%40en.%0D%0A+++OPTIONAL+%7B%3Fairline+dbo%3AiataAirlineCode+%3Fiata.%7D%0D%0A%7D+LIMIT+10%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on

Comment: @barny it's because of the dbpedia endpoint link it's weird. What  I am using http://fr.dbpedia.org/sparql. But When I use your dbpedia endpoint http://dbpedia.org/sparql/ I get results. I don't know to explain it

Comment: French DBpedia does **not** contain the same data as the English DBpedia. See http://fr.dbpedia.org/resource/Laker_Airways , it doesn't have any type declaration `dbo:Airline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SPARQL [works against the English language endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdfs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%3Fairline%20%3Fiata%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fairline%20a%20dbo%3AAirline.%0D%0A%20%20%20%3Fairline%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Laker%20Airways%22%40en.%0D%0A%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fairline%20dbo%3AiataAirlineCode%20%3Fiata.%7D%0D%0A%7D%20LIMIT%2010%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

So, use the English endpoint; it has different data from the French one.